# Enabling a css element to be clickable

Tags: css, shopify

**I have a store area in Shopify, which has CSS elements**

- And I want to make them clickable this is my CSS code

  I tried all sorts of tips written here And I did not succeed This is
  for my store And I would love to get a solution
- And I want to make them clickable this is my CSS code

Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

I have an area on the site And in this area there are icons Mouse over the icons has a moving animation I want the icons to be clickable And that they will link to the link within the site

```css
#shopByBodyPart {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#shopByBodyPart * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#shopByBodyPart dt {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  color: #6a6a6a;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  margin: 0 40px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0032/9370/8323/files/massage-part-all-min.png?6661") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 500px auto;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  background-position: -300px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  background-position: 0 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  background-position: -400px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4)::before {
  background-position: -200px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5)::before {
  background-position: -100px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1):hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2):hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3):hover::before {
  animation: steps-6 0.6s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4):hover::before {
  animation: steps-13 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5):hover::before {}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #shopByBodyPart dd {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px;
  }
  #shopByBodyPart dd::before {
    left: 10px;
  }
}


/** animation part start */

@keyframes steps-8 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -100px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -200px;
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -300px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -400px;
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -500px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -600px;
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -700px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -800px;
  }
}

@keyframes steps-16 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  6.25% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  18.75% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  31.25% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  43.75% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  56.25% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  68.75% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  81.25% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -1400px
  }
  93.75% {
    background-position-y: -1500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1600px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-13 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  7.6923076923076925% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  15.384615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  23.076923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  30.76923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  38.46153846153846% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  46.15384615384615% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  53.84615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  61.53846153846154% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  69.23076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  76.92307692307692% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  84.61538461538461% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  92.3076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-6 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  16.666666666666668% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  33.333333333333336% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  66.66666666666667% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  83.33333333333334% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
}
```

```html
<dl id="shopByBodyPart">
  <dt>SHOP BY BODY PART</dt>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/neck-and-shoulder">Neck &amp; Shoulder</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager">Back</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager">Waist</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/leg-foot-massager
  ">Leg &amp; Foot</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/full-body-massager">Full Body</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *clickable*? everything is clickable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! CSS doesn't make things "clickable", the markup does. You didn't tell us what exactly you are trying to make clickable. Is it the `::before` pseudo selectors? If so, you can't.

Comment: I have an area on the site
And in this area there are icons
Mouse over the icons has a moving animation
I want the icons to be clickable
And that they will link to the link within the site

Comment: Ok, that's perfect, now please edit your question to include that requirement.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS "element".

Answer (score 2):

Make the icons internal to the `a` tags instead. Then they will be part of the link

```css
#shopByBodyPart {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#shopByBodyPart * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#shopByBodyPart dt {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  color: #6a6a6a;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  margin: 0 40px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd>a{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd>a::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;*/
  transform: scale(0.8);
  background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0032/9370/8323/files/massage-part-all-min.png?6661") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 500px auto;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1)>a::before {
  background-position: -300px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2)>a::before {
  background-position: 0 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3)>a::before {
  background-position: -400px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4)>a::before {
  background-position: -200px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5)>a::before {
  background-position: -100px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1)>a:hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2)>a:hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3)>a:hover::before {
  animation: steps-6 0.6s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4)>a:hover::before {
  animation: steps-13 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5)>a:hover::before {}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #shopByBodyPart dd {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px;
  }
  #shopByBodyPart dd>a::before {
    left: 10px;
  }
}


/** animation part start */

@keyframes steps-8 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -100px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -200px;
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -300px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -400px;
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -500px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -600px;
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -700px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -800px;
  }
}

@keyframes steps-16 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  6.25% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  18.75% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  31.25% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  43.75% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  56.25% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  68.75% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  81.25% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -1400px
  }
  93.75% {
    background-position-y: -1500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1600px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-13 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  7.6923076923076925% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  15.384615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  23.076923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  30.76923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  38.46153846153846% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  46.15384615384615% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  53.84615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  61.53846153846154% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  69.23076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  76.92307692307692% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  84.61538461538461% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  92.3076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-6 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  16.666666666666668% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  33.333333333333336% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  66.66666666666667% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  83.33333333333334% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
}
```

```html
<dl id="shopByBodyPart">
  <dt>SHOP BY BODY PART</dt>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/neck-and-shoulder">Neck &amp; Shoulder</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager">Back</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager">Waist</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/leg-foot-massager
  ">Leg &amp; Foot</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/full-body-massager">Full Body</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<span>` tag to include an icon.

Example:

- **I.** HTML:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>SHOP BY BODY PART</dt>
    <dd>
        <a href="/" id="example-link">
            <span id="example-icon"></span>
            Opt. 1
        </a>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

- **II.** CSS:

```css
a#example-link > span#example-icon::after {
    background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0032/9370/8323/files/massage-part-all-min.png?6661") no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 500px auto;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The a tag is used already in the question. The question is asking how to make the icons clickable as well as the text.

Comment: modified and thx for the notice

Comment: It could be useful to create a runnable snippet from the code you suggest to test it out. There are a couple of reasons it may have a problem: the pseudo element does not have a content property and positioning/sizing needs checking. In any case is there a reason for adding more to the DOM rather than putting the pseudo element on the anchor tag?

Comment: CSS Sprite is also an option. Just to ensure it displayed correctly, CSS can do (even if it's an pseudo element). The principle of [Ico Moon](https://icomoon.io/) is also a `::before` element.

Answer (score 0):

`a` tags can link to external sites, where you need to put the full url, but when linking to the same site, the relative path is appropriate.

Provide a relative path to your other html files where you want to navigate when the user clicks the icons.

Ex:

```
<dd><a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager">Waist</a></dd>
```

Might be:

```
<dd><a href="./collections/back-massager.html">Waist</a></dd>
```

That all depends on where your html files are located.  Change the path to match the folder structure.  Read up on [html file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) if you get stuck.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about how to make the icons clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have put your `<a>` elements inside the `<dd>` elements. Just reverse them so that the `<dd>` is inside the `<a>`, like this:

```css
#shopByBodyPart {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#shopByBodyPart * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#shopByBodyPart dt {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  color: #6a6a6a;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  margin: 0 40px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0032/9370/8323/files/massage-part-all-min.png?6661") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 500px auto;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1)::before {
  background-position: -300px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  background-position: 0 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  background-position: -400px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4)::before {
  background-position: -200px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5)::before {
  background-position: -100px 0
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(1):hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(2):hover::before {
  animation: steps-8 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(3):hover::before {
  animation: steps-6 0.6s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(4):hover::before {
  animation: steps-13 1s steps(1) forwards;
}

#shopByBodyPart dd:nth-of-type(5):hover::before {}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #shopByBodyPart dd {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px;
  }
  #shopByBodyPart dd::before {
    left: 10px;
  }
}


/** animation part start */

@keyframes steps-8 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -100px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -200px;
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -300px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -400px;
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -500px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -600px;
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -700px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -800px;
  }
}

@keyframes steps-16 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  6.25% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  12.5% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  18.75% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  25% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  31.25% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  37.5% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  43.75% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  56.25% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  62.5% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  68.75% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  75% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  81.25% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
  87.5% {
    background-position-y: -1400px
  }
  93.75% {
    background-position-y: -1500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1600px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-13 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  7.6923076923076925% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  15.384615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  23.076923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  30.76923076923077% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  38.46153846153846% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  46.15384615384615% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
  53.84615384615385% {
    background-position-y: -700px
  }
  61.53846153846154% {
    background-position-y: -800px
  }
  69.23076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -900px
  }
  76.92307692307692% {
    background-position-y: -1000px
  }
  84.61538461538461% {
    background-position-y: -1100px
  }
  92.3076923076923% {
    background-position-y: -1200px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1300px
  }
}

@keyframes steps-6 {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0
  }
  16.666666666666668% {
    background-position-y: -100px
  }
  33.333333333333336% {
    background-position-y: -200px
  }
  50% {
    background-position-y: -300px
  }
  66.66666666666667% {
    background-position-y: -400px
  }
  83.33333333333334% {
    background-position-y: -500px
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -600px
  }
}
```

```html
<dl id="shopByBodyPart">
  <dt>SHOP BY BODY PART</dt>
  <a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/neck-and-shoulder"><dd>Neck &amp; Shoulder</dd></a>
  <a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager"><dd>Back</dd></a>
  <a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/back-massager"><dd>Waist</dd></a>
  <a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/leg-foot-massager
  "><dd>Leg &amp; Foot</dd></a>
  <a href="https://www.naipo.co.il/collections/full-body-massager"><dd>Full Body</dd></a>
</dl>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML. [`a` is not a valid child of `dl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

Comment: In modern HTML, anchor elements are transparent – they disappear from the element hierarchy, so their children effectively move up a level in the DOM. See the spec for reference: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element. So I think you'll find that this is perfectly okay, and works in all major browsers.

Comment: It may work, it's [still not valid HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-dl-element) . It's better to have working valid html than invalid html that works *for now*

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes

Comment: That changes nothing in terms of validity as a child of `dl` .  It relates to what can be a valid child of `a` . If `a` was a valid child of `dl` then it would be included. The fact that this markup fails in W3Cs own validation tool (https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is a pretty strong indicator that this is invalid.